# Requested value 'PersistedNotification' was not found TFS exception

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

When I try to query all Event Subscriptions from Visual Studio Online I receive the following error:
"Requested value 'PersistedNotification' was not found."

My code:

```
var server = TfsProvider.GetServer(tfsUri);

var eventService = (IEventService)server.GetService(typeof(IEventService));

var subscriptions = eventService.GetAllEventSubscriptions(); // Exception here
```

Comment: Same here, I guess someone from the MS Team might have to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be fixed in the 2015 RC build of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` (build 14.0.22821.0)

See this answer for assembly location: [Where can I find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30138669/3396059)

Answer (score 0):

I work arounded this problem by calling overload of GetAllEventSubscriptions() method:

```
var subscriptions = eventService.GetAllEventSubscriptions("My Notification Classification");
```

I am lucky enough and I exactly know value of the parameter. Geting list of all event subscriptions from VSO is still a problem.

Here is example how I create the subscription:

```
var preference = new DeliveryPreference
                 {
                     Schedule = DeliverySchedule.Immediate,
                     Type = DeliveryType.Soap,
                      Address = deliveryAddress,
                 };

var id = eventService.SubscribeEvent(EventType, string.Empty, preference, "My Notification Classification");
```