# Team Foundation Server 2015 Custom Git Build Activities - Where do I get the required references

Tags: tfs, workflow, tfs-2015

I am attempting to get our custom activities compiling under TFS2015. The project has two activities, one for TFS source control another for TFSGit.

With the team foundation binaries no longer installed into the GAC and some namespaces changed things are no longer compiling since Visual Studio 2015 RC.

Installing the NuGet package "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" results in 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities still missing. I haven't been able to locate the NuGet package for this or a valid reference which works with the NuGet package "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client".

I have attempted to follow the comments in [Where can I find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138669/where-can-i-find-microsoft-teamfoundation-build-client-in-visual-studio-2015). However I still have this error.

The best answer I have found so far is to create a powershell script like:
https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink/blob/master/Tfs/lib/Copy-Libraries.ps1#L8

Yet I am still uncertain as to which files are correct to reference. The versions I get in the example above are lower than those in the NuGet package, which are again different to those on the TFS server.

A classic example of this is that the Lib2GitSharp reference seems to be strongly named by Microsoft. Making the Lib2GitSharp NuGet package incompatible.

So in summary; where is the definitive location for TFS Activity references?

Comment: Stop using the XAML build system as soon as possible. It's deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reference the build activities from the folder in the matching version of VS for the build controller you are targeting.  For VS 2015 it would be this folder by default

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer